# Which planar curve has curvature linearly on arc length?

Tags: differential-geometry

Which planar curve has natural equation

$ k(s) = a*s $   ?

where
k(s) is curvature function on arc lenght parameterization and $ a \neq 0$

Answer (score 3):

[Cornu's Spiral aka the Clothoid](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CornuSpiral.html)